# How to analytically solve transport/diffusion system with linear degradation and mixed BCs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need to solve

$\partial_t u = D \partial_x^2 u - du$ (diffusion and degradation)

and

$\partial_t u = K \partial_x u - du$ (transport and degradation)

on $[0, L]$ with mixed BCs $u(t, 0) = \alpha$ and $\partial_t u(t, L) = -\varepsilon$.

Any help is welcome. I found information on solving the diffusion equation thanks to Fourier transforms but nothing when adding the degradation term. Thank you in advance !

Comment: What do you mean by '$du$ (diffusion and degradation)' and '$du$ (transport and degradation)'? Are '(diffusion and degradation)' and '(transport and degradation)' some other variables? Please make your notations clear.

Comment: @joy Sorry it's true that it is not clear ! you can just forget about what is between brackets it is not part of the equations but a name for it if you will, it just means that the first equation corresponds to diffusion and degradation of our variable u (respectively when you look at the two terms of the right hand member of the equation), and the second to transport and degradation